# Error en Activity2 de ejercicio de curso android studio

Tags: java, android

Estoy siguiendo los ejercicio de un curso de Android Studio. El ejercicio que me da un error trata de dos pantallas. En la primera se introduce una dirección de sitio web y en la segunda debe aparecer dicho sitio.

Al ejecutarlo me da solo un error que no acierto a solucionar.

Éste es el código java del Activity2:

```
package com.example.manuelreixach.proyecto112;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;



public class Actividad2 extends AppCompatActivity {
     private WebView webView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad2);


         webView1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);    Error:(21, 49) error: cannot find symbol variable webView

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String dato = bundle.getString("direccion");
        webView1.loadUrl("http://" + dato);
    }

    //public void onClick(View view) {
    //  Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    //        .setAction("Action", null
    // Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    //fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //  @Override).show();
    public void finalizar(View v) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te aparece?

Comment: Asegurate de que hay un elemento WebView existente en el layout activity_actividad2 cuyo id sea `webView`.

Comment: Hola Andrespengineer. Muchas gracias por tu aclaración. Efectivamente me faltaba colocar el id. Ahora se ejecuta la app para que ingrese la dirección del sitio, pero una vez pulso el botón VER se para la app. Tengo que investigar lo que ocurre ahora. Agradecido y saludos cordiales.

Comment: agregaste el permiso en el `AndroidManifest.xml` para el INTERNET ?

Comment: Hola marlonpya. Sí he agregado el permiso.

Comment: Hola Marlonpya. Si he agregado el permiso. Aparece la primera pantalla donde coloco el sitio web pero cuando doy al boton se para la aplicacion. Es decir no accede a la segunda pantalla. en esta segunda pantalla tengo las propiedades solo el id con webView y nada mas .Puede que me falta alguna propiedad mas. Aquí estoy perdido.Saludos